# How to prevent spamming of guest users? (best practices)

Tags: community, force.com-sites, security, guest-user

Business requirement requires guest user to create records in multiple objects. It is vulnerable for spamming users can create huge amount of data in short time. I am planning to add a recaptcha before record creation process to prevent it. What are the other security options provided by Salesforce for such cases? Is there any built in solution? Do you have any other suggestion to prevent such spamming acts?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the article to know more about captcha https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Adding_CAPTCHA_to_Force.com_Sites